# Why is the following convert command resulting in Segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, imagemagick

This is the command I am running (directly from the command line, logged in as root):

```
/usr/bin/convert '/var/storage/files/drupal/273f09ab5f8671d3c457719c7955063f.jpg' -resize 127x127! -quality '75' '/var/storage/files/drupal/imagecache/artwork_moreart/273f09ab5f8671d3c457719c7955063f.jpg'
```

The result of the command is just: `Segmentation fault`

Version of ImageMagic: ImageMagick 6.4.3 2009-02-25

Linux version: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

This image does exists and I have copied it to my local computer and opened it up with no issue.

Please let me know if there is additional information you need and how to get this information.

Comment: I would suggest you move along and upgrade your ImageMagick - a lot has changed in 6 years...

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I'm not really experienced with updating software on linux machines.

Comment: I use OS X on a Mac, so I am not the best person to ask - sorry! Have  a snuffle around on Google, or look here http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2012/10/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-sles-11-for-typo3 maybe.

Comment: I believe you'll need run [YaST](https://en.opensuse.org/YaST_Online_Update). For SUSE 11.4, the current version ImageMagick-6.6.5.8-7.3

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a *correct* command. The `!` needs backslash-escaping, first of all, otherwise it is interpreted by your shell, instead of by `convert`:

```
/usr/bin/convert \
 '/var/storage/files/drupal/273f09ab5f8671d3c457719c7955063f.jpg' \
 -resize 127x127\! -quality '75' \
 '/var/storage/files/drupal/imagecache/artwork_moreart/273f09ab5f8671d3c457719c7955063f.jpg'
```

If this doesn't work, try to surround the argument with single quotes too (like you did with your other arguments:

```
127x127\!   =>   '127x127\!'
```

The cause of your problem could also reside outside the `convert` binary, and be within the specific input JPEG you want process. You can try to rule this out by processing a set different input files. Start with the built-in IM test files `logo:`, `wizard:` and `netscape:`:

```
convert wizard:       \
  -resize "127x127\!" \
   127wiz.jpg

convert logo:         \
  -resize "127x127\!" \
   127log.jpg

convert netscape:     \
  -resize "127x127\!" \
   127net.jpg
```

Sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem directly here. SLES 11 with IM 6.4.3 is simply too ancient for me.